# After creating .exe file my flutter application (windows based) runs in background instead of running in foreground

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-windows

I have made my flutter project (windows platform) using android studio, I build the application than use inno setup to create a setup file but when I run the application after installation it runs in background not in foreground. I am creating windows based flutter application for the first time. I might miss some important thing like permission or something else please guide me how can I fix this issue. Also when I build the application and I run it from the release folder I works fine.

If you want to see any part of the code or anything else I can provide you. I don't know what are the relevant things to share.

I am using following dependencies(might be relevant):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  motion_toast: ^2.7.8
  sqflite_common_ffi: ^2.3.0+2
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  intl: ^0.18.1
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  get: ^4.6.6
```

I tried to build the setup by using winRar and inno setup but it still runs in background

Edit: Result of flutter doctor

```
PS C:\Users\ARcaN\Desktop\sharespace> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3516], locale en-PK)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)                        
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)                  
[√] Chrome - develop for the web                                                
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.4)  
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)                                             
[√] VS Code (version 1.83.0)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Are you using latest version of flutter? can you post `flutter doctor` result?

Comment: @Zahra I updated my question and add the result of flutter doctor

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `restorationScopeId` to materialApp based on [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119415#issuecomment-1480492795) issue like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      restorationScopeId: "some-Id-here",//Add this line
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

and [this is](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116699#issuecomment-1447196789) some more solutions if it didn't work.

Comment: I Tried both the solutions but it didn't work

Comment: Did you cleaned the project?

Comment: Yes, I did clean the project

Comment: Try running the exe file as Administrator.

Comment: No, still it didn't work? Is there anything I am missing or didn't notice? I am making the windows application for the first time so I think I might doing something wrong. If you want I can share you my code

Comment: The problem might be with `inno setup`, you can ask for help from their git repo, maybe it's a bug. You can also use `msix` to create setup file.

Comment: Okay I'll try msix